# Why doesn't self.object in a CreateView have an id after saving to the database?

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-class-based-views

Following the comment on the accepted answer on [django createview how to get the object that is created](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13309479/django-createview-how-to-get-the-object-that-is-created#comment18154004_13310257), I am attempting to use the id from a user created by a `CreateView` in its `get_success_url` method. However, even though it is definitely being saved to MySQL and receiving an id, when I access `self.object`, it doesn't have an id to use. The model does have an `id` property. Why wouldn't I be able to access the id? If I'm being led astray by the linked comment, what is the right way to get the id?

Reference code:

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models

class User(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    active = models.BooleanField(blank=True)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField()
    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'user'
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

**views.py**

```
from django.views.generic import CreateView
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from forms import AddUserForm

class AddUserView(CreateView):
    form_class = AddUserForm
    fields = ['name', 'active'] # id and created_date are auto-filled upon save
    template_name = 'webApp/add_user_form.html'

    def get_success_url(self):
        print self.object # Prints the name of the submitted user
        print self.object.id # Prints None
        return reverse("webApp:user:stepTwo", args=(self.object.id,))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's blank because the object is not actually receiving an id. That's because the `id` field should be an [AutoField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/models/fields/#autofield), not IntegerField, so that it is declared as auto-incrementing.

Actually though you should not declare it at all: an primary key AutoField named id is [the default](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/db/models/#automatic-primary-key-fields), so you should leave it out.

Note you'll need to migrate your database table, or drop and recreate it, after you make this change.

Comment: Excellent! I just used `inspectdb` to come up with that model, so I was surprised that the problem was there. Now to go through and remove all my `id` fields...

Comment: Yeah, inspectdb should be thought of as a rough draft, not a full translation of your schema. It has problems with foreign keys too.

Comment: Oh, any general advice on the foreign key issues? I haven't run into problems with them yet.