# Creating two models in generic CreateView

Tags: django, django-views

Here I am trying to register log if the new category has been created. But this is not working.I am using generic View to create the category model now I want to add LogEntry to this model so tried like this but it is throwing error.

```
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value:    
'CreateCategory' object has no attribute 'object'
```

views

```
 class CreateCategroy(SuccessMessageMixin, generic.CreateView):
        model = Category
        fields = ['title']
        template_name = 'add_category.html'
        success_url = reverse_lazy('list_category')
        success_message = 'Created Successfully.'

        def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
            LogEntry.objects.log_action(user_id=self.request.user.pk,
                                        content_type_id=ContentType.objects.get_for_model(Category).pk,
                                        object_id=self.object.pk,
                                        object_repr=force_text(self.object),
                                        change_message='New Category has been created.',
                                        action_flag=1
                                        )
```

Comment: Is that the full code? I'm assuming the `object` in this case is going to refer to the new `Category`? If so, you'll need to actually create this first so you actually have a reference to it.

Comment: yes it's the full code to create the category. Before it worked now I added `LogEntry` model with `post` method then it neither creates the category nor log and throws the error. @urbanespaceman

Comment: Is this helpful:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25212745/why-doesnt-self-object-in-a-createview-have-an-id-after-saving-to-the-database

Comment: Also, I note your error says "CreateCategory", but your code misspells this as "Categroy" - is this just a typo in your question, or are (if you copy/pasted) you maybe actually calling a different method?