# Django - Pass Foreign Key to Second Model

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I'm trying to create a fairly simply input view for a django webapp.  I have the following simply models set up.  At the end I've included the traceback as well.  The question is how do I create an object in the CreateView class and pass the foreign key of the parent object?

```
#models.py
#imports...

class Client(models.Model):

    client_id = models.AutoField(
        primary_key=True)

class Item(models.Model):

    client = models.ForeignKey(
        Client,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    item_id = models.AutoField(
        primary_key=True)
```

The idea is to have a list of unique clients and then each client can have a list of unique items.  The items are linked to the client.

```
#views.py
#imports...

class ItemCreate(CreateView):
    model = Item
    fields = [
        #list of fields
        ]

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.client_id = self.request.client.client_id
        return super(PermCreate, self).form_valid(form)
```

Given these two class models, I'm trying to `CreateView` that will create a new `Item` and have it attached to the respective `Client`.  I have a `ListView` that will iterate through `Items` for a given `Client`.  The `ListView` has a link to the `CreateView` (Add New Item).  I am not having a problem with the `pk`'s in the views or even getting to the `CreateView`.  I can't get the `CreateView` to save the object.  I get an error that says...

```
'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'client'
```

The code above is derived from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10382838/how-to-set-foreignkey-in-createview) question.  I've tried several iterations of the argument to set `form.instance.client_id` but a `request` is likely the wrong call.  The examples given are using `user` calls not per se the table foreign key information.

I've also tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13309479/django-createview-how-to-get-the-object-that-is-created) (using the primary keys for my models) and I've tired accessing the URL pk from the template tags - but figured if I can't access them in the the views object that getting from the template would be more difficult.

## Traceback

```
File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  35.             response = get_response(request)

File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  128.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  126.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in view
  69.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in dispatch
  89.         return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py" in post
  172.         return super().post(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py" in post
  142.             return self.form_valid(form)

File "/Users/billarmstrong/Documents/GitHub/Core/WebDataCollect/Pro/ProWP/views.py" in form_valid
  55.         form.instance.client_id = self.request.client.client_id

Exception Type: AttributeError at /ProWP/2/additem/
Exception Value: 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'client'
```

## Update

```
# urls.py

    path('<int:pk>/additem/', views.ItemCreate.as_view(), name='item-add'),
    path('<int:pk>/item/', views.ItemView.as_view(), name='itemview'),
```

I've also made some progress.  I've started working with example 1 code and found that if I set `form.instance.client_id = 2` that it will appropriately add the object with the foreign key of `2`.  So the issue is trying to get the originating POST `pk`.  I've tried example 2 and it throws `(1048, "column 'client_id' cannot be null")` which i interpret to mean that I'm not getting the `Item` object.  So, I tried example 3 and `(1048, "Column 'client_id' cannot be null")`.

```
# views.py
# Example 1

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.client_id = 2
        return super(PermCreate, self).form_valid(form)

# Example 2

    def form_valid(self, form):
        pk = self.kwargs.get("perm_id", None)
        form.instance.client_id = pk
        return super(PermCreate, self).form_valid(form)


# Example 3

    def form_valid(self, form):
        pk = self.kwargs.get("client_id", None)
        form.instance.client_id = pk
        return super(PermCreate, self).form_valid(form)
```

## Update 2

after testing and `print`ing - I think the issue is in my `request` or `kwargs.get` variable.  Since the entire thing works when I hard code the `client_id` in the instance - I've concluded that the instance does in fact exist with all the appropriate information - including the URL primary key - but I'm not getting the right variable name to access it.  I know it isn't `item_id` or `client_id`.

## Update 3

Both `request` and `KWARGS` work. After working through every possible variable to get to the primary key it turned out to be `pk`.

So rather than using either the `client_id` or the `item_id`, the value is held in `pk`.  Any explanation would be helpful.  I'm guessing that the URL actually sets the variable from my `urls.py` file - but not 100 certain.

Comment: Please show us the URL config for the view. Also how do you know in your `CreateView` which `Client` you're working with?

Comment: is' Client` linked to a specific instance of `User` [auth.models.User]?

Comment: @solarissmoke with the hard coded reference to the `client_id` all the URLs and Views work.  I've posted the references so that you can see the pk variables in the URLs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
form.instance.client_id = self.request.client.client_id
```

this line should be like,

```
form.instance.client_id = self.request.POST['client'].client_id
```

or

```
form.instance.client_id = self.request.GET['client'].client_id
```

Depending upon request type.

Comment: the above code throws `(1048, "Column 'client_id' cannot be null")`.  I did notice that I can use the .get() method and it "works" - but I get a `(1048, "Column 'client_id' cannot be null")` error.  Which lead to the update posted above.  The request type is a POST.  I do now see that I'm not exactly sure what object I'm getting the `form.instance` from as both keys produce `null` values.